# centos support for xen

Tags: linux

recently I have read about red hat leaving the support of xen for kvm. Does centos will do the same, does anyone knows that.

question: does support means working with xen development or does it mean that xen wont work with redhat any more.

thanks

Comment: Might get a better response on servefault.com, but it is a good question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Xen isn't on the centos 7 distro but Kvm is...
2. Manually installing Xen on Centos 7 is a bad idea, Xen requires a different Python version than the one that is available on the Centos Distro.
3. Go for Debian if you want to install Xen.

Answer (score 0):

Xen is being dropped in favor of kvm. Centos always follows Redhat that is their thing.

IMHO kvm is a much better virtualization solution overall.